# extjs 3 - Check which tabs are hidden and which are not in tabpanel

Tags: extjs, tabpanel

I have a tabpanel where some tabs are hidden. How can i check which tabs are hidden and which are not.

For example:
- There are 5 tabs tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5. tab2 and tab4 are hidden.
- if i m in tab1 then tab2.hidden is true or tab2.isVisible() is false
- if i m in tab1 then tab3.hidden is true or tab3.isVisible() is false

So how can i check the actual hidden tabs????
Thanks a lot for help
Regards

Comment: I don't follow. Are you looking for how to see whether a particular tab is active? `isVisible` doesn't check whether a tab is "on top" or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are looking for the visibility of tab strip item. You can get the tab's node with `getTabEl(tab)` on the TabPanel. From the tab you can use:

```
Ext.get(tab.ownerCt.getTabEl(tab)).isVisible();
```

Note, regardless of the name `getTabEl` returns a DOM node not an `Ext.Element` which is why you need the `Ext.get` (or `Ext.fly` if you like to live dangerously).